# vim replace character to \n

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I need replace all ; to \n , but `:%s/;/\n/gc` not works

Comment: question for a superuser

Answer (score 53, accepted):

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

> When searching:   \n is newline, \r is
>   CR (carriage return = Ctrl-M = ^M)
>   When replacing:   \r is newline, \n is
>   a null byte (0x00).

Comment: doh! the first thing about vim that i hate. i love vim ... but wow ... this one is evil.

Comment: Is there any way to change this behaviour? I want \n to be LF and \r to be CR - *always*.

Comment: Was trying to match multi-line stuff, including newlines, and replace them with matching groups containing newlines.  That wasn't working, as I was getting the whole \n vs \r problem.  The only way I've found to get around this is to replace \n with some improbable sequence, do whatever regex stuff I was trying to do (using the improbable sequence in place of where I would've used \n), then replace the improbable sequence with \r.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `\r` as the replacement instead: `:%s/;/\r/gc`