# How to Put Newline Characters in Substitutions of Regular Expressions of GVim

Tags: regex, vim, newline, substitution

I use GVim on Windows 7.

I want to learn how to put newline characters by using regex substitutions. To do this I try to use \r and \n metacharacters but the substituted text doesn't show normal newlines.

For example, at the beginning I have:

```
line 1
line 2
```

[image: Before substitution]

I use the following substitution expression:

```
:%s/\n/\n\n/g
```

Then GVim produces the following text:

```
line 1^@^@line 2^@^@
```

[image: After substitution with \n as newline characters]

Instead, if I use \r\n in the substitution expression

```
:%s/\n/\r\n/g
```

Then GVim produces the following text:

```
line 1
^@line 2
^@
```

[image: After substitution with \r\n as newline]

What are those ^@ characters?

How to use newline characters in the substitution expression properly?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### ^@ is a nul

---

For some reason, vim wants to see `\r` in the replacement text in order to insert a newline. (`\n` in the replacement inserts a nul.)

So, after succesfully locating newlines by running `/\n`, try:

```
s//\r/
```

Or to add an extra newline:

```
s/$/\r/
```

On the pattern side, `\r` means an actual (015) CR character, leading to the following strange-looking command when you want to replace returns with newlines:

```
s/\r/\r/
```

No, it's not a no-op.

Comment: In my Vim 7.3 on Windows 7, the suggested `s/\r/\r/` gives error 'E486: Pattern not found: \r'. Was it tested to work on a prior version somehow?

Comment: For more info on metacharacter usage difference in search vs. replace, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3966089/2664868).

Answer (score 5):

This

```
s/\r/\r/
```

fails.
But

```
s/\n/\r/
```

works fine.